# Displaying average number inputted by user greater than 50 and product of all numbers divisible by 3

Tags: c++

I need to write a program that will get a series of numbers until a 0 is entered. The program then
displays the average of all numbers greater than 50 and the product of all numbers
divisible by 3.

I can already get the average numbers but when I entered less than 50 the program breaks and also I was not able to get the product of number divisible by 3.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int total=0, result,num, inputCount=0, product = 1;
    double average;
    do{
         cout << "Input numbers : " << endl;
         cin >> num;

        if(num>50){
            inputCount++;
            total = total+num;
         }

    }
while(num!=0);          
    cout<<"Average of numbers greater than 50 is ";
    cout<<total/inputCount;
    if(num % 3 == 0)
         {
            num*=num;
             cout<< endl << "Product of all numbers divisible by 3 is " << num <<endl;
         }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I expect that the result will be :

```
Input num : 90
Input num : 9
Input num : 0
Average of numbers greater than 50 is : 90
Product of all numbers divisible by 3 is :  810
```

Since the user inputted 90, 9, and 0 the program stops getting input when 0 when entered and then the average of numbers greater than 50 is 90 since 90 is the only number that is greater than 50 while 90 and 9 are divisible by 3 so 90*9 = 810. But the actual output I get was

```
Average of numbers greater than 50 is : 90
Product of all numbers divisible by 3 is :  0
```

I tried doing the following, but when I entered 0, it also multiplied in the loop. how do I prevent that from happening?

```
do{ 
    cout << "Input numbers : " << endl; cin >> num; 
    if(num>50){ inputCount++; total = total+num; } 
    if(num % 3 == 0) { product = product * num; } 
    cout<< endl << "Product of all numbers divisible by 3 is " << product <<endl; 
} while(num!=0);
```

Comment: The whole "all numbers divisable by 3" part needs to be inside the loop as well. If you do some [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) you should hopefully realize that after the loop all you have is the last numbered entered, which will always be `0`.

Comment: `num*=num;` simply squares `num`. That ain't what you want. Surely it's `product *= num;`?

Comment: do{
   cout << "Input numbers : " << endl;
      cin >> num;
   
  if(num>50){
   inputCount++;
   total = total+num;
   }
  if(num % 3 == 0)
   {
   product = product * num;
    
   }
  cout<< endl << "Product of all numbers divisible by 3 is " << product <<endl;
   
 }
while(num!=0);  
Tried doing this but when I entered 0, it also multiplied in the loop. how do I prevent that from happening?

Comment: dont add code in comments but rather edit your question. Code in comments is almost unreadable. I fixed some formatting for you and added the comment to the question. If you dont like my edit, fix it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55588596/edit)

Comment: btw very nice first question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should move that `if (num % 3 == 0` into the loop.

```
if (num > 50) {
    inputCount++;
    total = total + num;
}
if (num % 3 == 0 && num > 0)
{
    product *= num;
}
```

Also note the `&& num > 0`, because `0` is also divisible by `3`, and you want to ignore that or else your product is going to be `0`. Alternatively, you could change your loop to abort on `0` before doing those checks. Outside of the loop, you should only have the output:

```
std::cout << "Product of all numbers divisible by 3 is " << product << std::endl;
```

---

On as side note, I would recommend handling the case for when no number greater than 50 is entered:

```
if (inputCount > 0) {
    std::cout << "Average of numbers greater than 50 is " << total / inputCount << std::endl;
}
else {
    std::cout << "No number greater than 50 was entered." << std::endl;
}
```

Otherwise the program crashes when this happens.